# How do I tell if Razor is enabled in my existing MVC project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an existing ASP.NET project updated from VS2010 to VS2015.  It had some MVC portions that I would like to expand on, and would like to take advantage of Razor.  How can I tell if that is available or can it be enabled if it is not? Can I mix Razor with non-Razor MVC?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Razor uses the library 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor'; you'll need to make sure your project includes a reference to this library.  You can also check that the nuget package is installed by going to Tools -> Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages For Solution:

[image: Visual Studio Nuget Package Razor]

> Can I mix Razor with non-Razor MVC?

If you're using MVC, the views you create will be .cshtml (assuming C#) and will support the Razor syntax by default.  You can also use traditional HTML, JavaScript, JQuery, etc in these .cshtml pages.  I'd have a look at Microsoft's Razor syntax doc:

[Razor Syntax Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor)

Comment: Selected this response for completeness. Thank you for both responses!

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost sure Razor comes by default with VS2015, just open an .cshtml file and try to write with Razor syntax.

```
@("Hello World!")
```